# tshark (wireshark) filters: Where are they located?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

While troubleshooting a MySQL issue, I came across [this command at commandlinefu](http://commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7001/capture-mysql-queries-sent-to-server):

```
tshark -i any -T fields -R mysql.query -e mysql.query
```

I am trying to understand it before I actually use it. Looking at the [man page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) helped me understand the options used. The [MySQL filter documentation](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/m/mysql.html) was also helpful. However, how can I actually **see** what the filter looks like? I'm *assuming* all the filters are saved in a directory somewhere. Is this assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS they're all compiled into */usr/lib/libwireshark.so*

All of the *filters* are called *dissectors* within the source code and are located in *epan/dissectors*.

The MySQL dissector is **epan/dissectors/packet-mysql.c**